# Normals not working properly, even if recalculated

Tags: modeling, normals

I have been making some models for a Unity project. I have a problem only with this model,

[image: 1]

idk if they are the normals because it seems that they are fine.

[image: 2]

the funny thing is that in Unity looks fine, but in blender not.

Comment: could you please share the object with the problem? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sure  https://pasteall.org/blend/0bde5189f2dc40d88a5d55c5da29c69b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Material Settings*, switch back the *Blend Mode* to *Opaque*, I guess it's your problem?

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it :D